# How to properly forward TCP and UDP traffic between interfaces using iptables?

Tags: networking, vpn, port-forwarding, iptables

**ServerA**

- eth0 internet interface
- wg0 vpn interface 10.66.66.1

**ServerB**

- wg0 vpn interface 10.66.66.2

How can I forward traffic from eth0 to wg0 10.66.66.2 using iptables?
I want to forward the following TCP and UDP ports to **ServerB**

**TCP:** 2302, 27015-27030, 27036-27037
**UDP:** 2302, 4380, 27000-27031, 27036

I tried already, to forward everything for texting, but to no avail.

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface eth0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables --table nat -A POSTROUTING --out-interface wg0 -j MASQUERADE
```

EDIT:

results of `iptables -L` do I need to mind a ambiguity between legacy and "normal" iptables

```
[root@vmd40065 ~]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
# Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy to see them

[root@vmd40065 ~]# iptables-legacy -L
bash: iptables-legacy: command not found...
```

Comment: It's actually DS-Lite btw, unrelated to DSL.

Comment: CentOS 8 has been EOL since 31st December 2021.

Comment: @mtak, yes I will update to Centos stream soon

Comment: Is IP Forwarding enabled on `ServerA`?

Comment: yes it is via 
`net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1 in sysctl.conf`
and
`[root@... ~]# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`
`net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### IP Forwarding

> How can I forward traffic from eth0 to wg0 10.66.66.2 using iptables?

You can't do that with iptables (alone). With iptables you can do filtering and NAT, but iptables doesn't do packet forwarding.

To get your incoming packets forwarded, you need to enable IP forwarding in the kernel. Using the command `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward` you can check if IP forwarding is already enabled.

Quote from [Linux kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/ip-sysctl.html):

```
0 - disabled (default)
not 0 - enabled

Forward Packets between interfaces.
```

You can enable this by executing `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`, but this change is not permanent, it gets reset on reboot. To make this permanent, you'd need a configuration entry (`net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`) in one of the sysctl configuration files (eg. `/etc/sysctl.conf`). See `man sysctl.conf` for a complete list of configuration files.

If you want to limit what is being forwarded, you can add more parameters to your *FORWARD* rule, for example:

- `--protocol tcp` or `--protocol udp`
- `--destination-port 27000:27031`

See `man iptables` and `iptables-extensions` for more parameters if needed.

Note that adding *ACCEPT* rules to the *FORWARD* chain has no effect, if the chain policy is *ACCEPT* anyway and you don't have any *DROP* rules.

### NAT

Your iptables SNAT rule in the *POSTROUTING* chain looks correct.

If the traffic coming from eth0 doesn't already have its destination address set to `10.66.66.2`, then you also need a DNAT rule in the *PREROUTING* chain. This is to modify the destination address of the packets, so the routing can select the outgoing interface accordingly. This should be something like this:

```
iptables --table nat --append PREROUTING --in-interface eth0
--protocol udp --destination-port 27000:27031
--jump DNAT --to-destination 10.66.66.2:27000-27031
```

### Debugging

For debugging purpose it can be helpful to:

- Observe the traffic with `tcpdump` on both servers.
- Add `--verbose` to iptables when listing rules. This way you can see how many packets (if any) got affected by which rule.

Comment: thanks for your answer
I got all of this setup, but it does still not work.
Can I maybe check somehow if previous attempts of mine hinder successful traffic?

Comment: I think you might need to `DNAT` on the `PREROUTING` chain too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945233/iptables-forward-and-input . DNAT the incoming traffic on `eth0` to `10.66.66.2`. Then, depending on the routing table, you'll hit the `FORWARD` chain and then the `POSTROUTING` chain where your `MASQUERADE` is. **Be careful that you don't `DNAT` yourself out of the box though.** You don't want to get inadvertently locked out.

Comment: @PrestonManess my answer was based on the assumption that the incoming traffic is already addressed to the VPN IP address. I think you are right and i edited the answer, adding information about DNAT. Thank you!

Comment: thank you guys, its all working now
my friends and I can now connect to the DayZ server
I had to switch also my WireGuard config on the Server B to route all traffic through it `AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0,::/0`

and small thing, I had to put the last part behind the DNAT
`iptables --table nat --append PREROUTING --in-interface eth0 --protocol udp --destination-port 27000:27031 --jump DNAT --to-destination 10.66.66.2:27000-27031`